# Need advice on new device regulatory requirements

Tags: power, ce, ul, regulatory

I have designed a product (device) that runs on 12 VDC (similar to a laptop). It is AC powered using a (table top), detachable switching power supply 100 VAC to 240 VAC, 50-60 Hz, again exactly like a laptop PC. The external Power supply with cord is already among many others, UL, CSA, CE  approved. Do I need to get any more regulatory approvals on the device? If not, can I tag the device with these approvals as self certified.

Comment: only if you do not modify the PS in any way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I take it that it is ok to tag my device with the regulatory symbols. Right?

Comment: @S.Chaoui No it is not okay, but feel free to check with UL/CSA on their opinion.

Comment: https://standardscatalog.ul.com/standards/en/standard_1310_6

Answer (score 0):

### You can't tag if you didn't test...

You cannot claim your device is approved by those standards bodies if you have not sought approval from them. The fact that your power supply is certified means that you will face much less difficulty getting your device approved (all of the AC standards have already been met and tested for you, yay!), *but your device is not necessarily compliant with other relevant standards just because you used a good power supply*.

### There's more to certification than just the AC/DC power supply...

Depending on what your device actually does (medical, industrial, consumer) and what devices it actually contains (motors, electrodes, etc) and what voltages are present during operation and after power is disconnected, you will have to comply with relevant standards. Another set of standards to worry about concerns unintentional radiation (regulated by the FCC in the US and others worldwide).

So simple put, *Power supply certification is insufficient to claim compliance* and if you do so, you will be violating those laboratories trademarks and can be held liable for those damages.

Comment: The device is a consumer table mount paint spray booth that uses a 12 VDC 80W, 9" diameter sealed motor fan and nothing else but a speed control board. What UL/CE standards should I consult?. In normal operation, the fan is turned ON to exhaust paint over spray through a set of 3 filters. Do fan motors produce radiation?

Comment: Yes. Fan motors produce radiation (lots of it). Since you're over 70W, you'll have to have a Power-Factor-Correcting (PFC) equipped power supply. As to specific standards you'll have EMI/EMC (e.g. FCC rules) from the motor and the control board (which probably has a >1MHz oscillator on it), PFC Power Supply (EU rules), UL appliance and human factors standards to contend with (if you need UL/CSA/etc).